# chromedriver.exe has stopped working when running the selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I solve this error?

> Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build
>   info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05
>   19:15:17' System info: host: 'PC027', ip: '192.168.1.110', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_77' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Maybe some more details? It's not even a question, but just a piece of exception log...

Comment: Did it timeout?